# Fichero PHP con phpinfo() salta error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE en navegador

Tags: php, linux, apache

En el servidor donde estoy ejecutando el código es un Apache, con PHP 7.0 y MySQL 5.6. La máquina es una Raspberry PI 2.

Estoy intentando por todos los medios solucionar el problema que tengo con el fichero que ejecuta el phpinfo(), la estructura del fichero es bastante simple, así que no debería entrañar ningún error en la programación:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Ese sería el contenido. Lo extraño de todo es que he probado a ejecutar otros código PHP, y me los ejecuta tan normal, mostrando el resultado.

He revisado los ficheros de log, pero no veo nada que a mi me indique que puede ser. Lo adjunto.

```
> [Sun Sep 03 11:18:16.266534 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 332] AH01909:
> 127.0.0.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name [Sun Sep 03 11:18:25.642147 2017] [ssl:warn]
> [pid 463] AH01909: 127.0.0.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include
> an ID which matches the server name [Sun Sep 03 11:18:26.284286 2017]
> [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 463] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian)
> OpenSSL/1.0.2l configured -- resuming normal operations [Sun Sep 03
> 11:18:26.321399 2017] [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00094: Command line:
> '/usr/sbin/apache2'
> *** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x02170d08 *** [Sun Sep 03 11:21:10.439716 2017] [core:notice] [pid
> 463] AH00052: child pid 554 exit signal Aborted (6) [Sun Sep 03
> 11:21:11.454156 2017] [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00052: child pid 556
> exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
> *** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x02170d08 *** [Sun Sep 03 11:21:12.484748 2017] [core:notice] [pid
> 463] AH00052: child pid 557 exit signal Aborted (6) [Sun Sep 03
> 11:21:13.679268 2017] [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00052: child pid 559
> exit signal Segmentation fault (11) [Sun Sep 03 11:21:14.680813 2017]
> [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00052: child pid 567 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11)
> *** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x02170d08 *** [Sun Sep 03 11:21:15.722504 2017] [core:notice] [pid
> 463] AH00052: child pid 1094 exit signal Aborted (6) [Sun Sep 03
> 11:21:16.774099 2017] [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00052: child pid 1101
> exit signal Segmentation fault (11) [Sun Sep 03 11:21:16.774381 2017]
> [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00052: child pid 1102 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sun Sep 03 11:21:19.059100 2017]
> [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00052: child pid 1109 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11)
> *** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x02170d08 *** [Sun Sep 03 11:21:20.060520 2017] [core:notice] [pid
> 463] AH00052: child pid 1110 exit signal Aborted (6)
> *** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x02170d08 *** [Sun Sep 03 11:23:07.212383 2017] [core:notice] [pid
> 463] AH00052: child pid 1111 exit signal Aborted (6) [Sun Sep 03
> 11:23:08.309492 2017] [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00052: child pid 1114
> exit signal Segmentation fault (11) [Sun Sep 03 11:23:09.410063 2017]
> [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00052: child pid 1123 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11) [Sun Sep 03 11:23:09.410403 2017]
> [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00052: child pid 1124 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11)
> *** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x02170d08 *** [Sun Sep 03 11:23:10.428996 2017] [core:notice] [pid
> 463] AH00052: child pid 1141 exit signal Aborted (6) [Sun Sep 03
> 11:23:11.459615 2017] [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00052: child pid 1471
> exit signal Segmentation fault (11) [Sun Sep 03 11:23:11.459950 2017]
> [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00052: child pid 1478 exit signal
> Segmentation fault (11)
> *** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x02170d08 *** [Sun Sep 03 11:23:12.501763 2017] [core:notice] [pid
> 463] AH00052: child pid 1479 exit signal Segmentation fault (11) [Sun
> Sep 03 11:23:13.503197 2017] [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00052: child
> pid 1482 exit signal Segmentation fault (11) [Sun Sep 03
> 11:23:13.503412 2017] [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00052: child pid 1483
> exit signal Aborted (6)
> *** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x02170d08 *** [Sun Sep 03 11:23:30.538570 2017] [core:notice] [pid
> 463] AH00052: child pid 1484 exit signal Aborted (6) [Sun Sep 03
> 11:31:55.816709 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 463] AH00171: Graceful
> restart requested, doing restart AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably
> determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1.
> Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message [Sun
> Sep 03 11:32:04.031294 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 463] AH01909:
> 127.0.1.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name [Sun Sep 03 11:32:04.070957 2017]
> [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 463] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian)
> OpenSSL/1.0.2l configured -- resuming normal operations [Sun Sep 03
> 11:32:04.071161 2017] [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00094: Command line:
> '/usr/sbin/apache2'
> *** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x021dac08 *** [Sun Sep 03 11:32:23.282816 2017] [core:notice] [pid
> 463] AH00052: child pid 3228 exit signal Aborted (6) [Sun Sep 03
> 11:34:29.718002 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 463] AH00171: Graceful
> restart requested, doing restart AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably
> determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1.
> Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message [Sun
> Sep 03 11:34:33.284153 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 463] AH01909:
> 127.0.1.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name [Sun Sep 03 11:34:33.285335 2017]
> [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 463] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian)
> OpenSSL/1.0.2l configured -- resuming normal operations [Sun Sep 03
> 11:34:33.285438 2017] [core:notice] [pid 463] AH00094: Command line:
> '/usr/sbin/apache2'
> *** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x01f775d8 *** [Sun Sep 03 11:34:34.380139 2017] [core:notice] [pid
> 463] AH00052: child pid 3752 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

Si alguien ve un error que pueda ser el problema, que me indique que debo hacer. Estoy empezando en este tema de configuración de servidores web en Linux y se que hay cosas que se me están escapando, pero no se cuál.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que podrías tener un par de problemas a solucionar:

1. El primero habilitar los mensajes de error en la configuración de Apache, algo está fallando pero no se está mostrando el qué.
2. El segundo podría ser debido a temas de permisos, si otros archivos PHP te funcionan, es posible que éste en particular tenga mal los permisos y apache no pueda leerlo.

Comment: Si eso mismo hice, de hecho puse los permisos al máximo en dicho fichero para ver si así funcionaba, pero nada. También están activos los errores, todos los errores, que sean mostrados, pero tampoco.

Comment: Aunque los errores que has colocado son graves los había ignorado por no tener nada que ver con php y estar corriendo sobre una rpi. Pero lo cierto es que parece que el proceso de tu servidor apache muere por algún motivo (exit signal Segmentation fault (11)) Esto significa que el servidor recibe la petición, pero es incapaz de devolver una respuesta, muere, y el navegador te indica con ese error que no ha recibido nada. Quizás una rpi no sea la plataforma más estable para correr un apache, podrías tener un problema de compilación de apache o un problema de hardware.

Comment: Podrías comprobar los logs del sistema, en concreto los del kernel. Tu kernel podría estar matando el proceso por consumir demasiada RAM.